# IndexDB records takes up more space than shown

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, indexeddb

I am having a strange problem with IndexDB in google chrome. I am saving large amounts of data to indexdb. However, the Application tab's dashboard (devtools) shows that I used more space than my data holds. I am going to explain via two screenshots:

[image: IndexDB entries]

In this image, as you can see, my data holds only 1.7 megabytes. There is nothing else stored in the IndexDB other than these two entries. However, when I switch to the "Clear Storage" section to see overall storage usage for this domain, I see something quite strange.

[image: Shows more space used than required]

Here, it shows that there are 59.3 megabytes of data stored in IndexDB. I don't understand what's the issue here to be honest. I clear site data and save same data in the cache, result is the same. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome's implementation of Indexed DB compacts space lazily, so it's unsurprising that it often shows more data use than expected. That said, this is 10x what you have stored, which seems unusual.

You should create a minimal standalone repro and report it at https://new.crbug.com